# Sort big files in Amazon S3

Tags: sorting, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bigdata

I have a big file (attribute file) in my Amazon S3 bucket in .zip form. It is around 30 gb when unzipped. The file is updated every 2 days.

```
INDEX HIEGHT GENDER AGE
00125 155 MALE 15
01002 161 FEMALE 18
00410 173 MALE 17
00001 160 MALE 20
00010 159 FEMALE 22
.
.
.
```

My use-case is such that I want to iterate once through the sorted attribute file in 1 program run. Since the zipped file is around 3.6 gb and is updated every 2 days, my code downloads it from S3 everytime. (Probably I can use caching but currently I am not using that.)

I want the file to be sorted. Since the unzipped file is large and expected to grow more everytime, I do not want to unzip it during the code run.

What I am trying to achieve is following:-

I have other files- metric files. They are **relatively smaller** in size ( ~20-30 mb) and are **sorted**.

```
INDEX MARKS
00102 45
00125 62
00342 134
00410 159
.
.
.
```

Using the INDEX, I want to create METRIC-ATTRIBUTE file for each METRIC file. If the attribute file was also sorted, I could do something similar to merging two sorted lists, taking only the common INDEX rows. It would take O(SIZE_OF_ATTRIBUTE_FILE + SIZE_OF_METRIC_FILE) space and time.

What is the best way to sort it( the attribute file)? An aws solution is preferred.

Comment: I cannot use Aws Lambda as its /tmp size limit is 512 mb.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Comment: if you dont/cant use lambda, you could still use EMR and can process the zip file

Comment: What is the format of the data inside the ZIP file (eg is it a zipped CSV file)? Can you provide more details about what you wish to do with the file? For example, do you need to process the data only in sorted order? Do you output a result somewhere? If you can provide more details, we can suggest a more suitable solution. (For example, Amazon EMR could be useful in some circumstances, depending on what you intend to do with the resulting data.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: It's like each line has 5-6 words, first word being used as index to sort it. The remaining are the attributes for this particular index.
There is a second file, which is smaller around 20 mb and is sorted. This file contains some indices and metrics associated with it. 
I want to add attributes along with the metrics. I want to do something like merging two sorted list, keeping only the common ones.

Comment: Feel free to update your Question with a sample of both files and this type of explanation, so that people can propose suitable options. The more detail, the better the chance of a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [AWS Athena service](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/). Athena service can operate over big S3 files (even if they are zipped). You could create one table for every S3 file and run SQL queries against them.

Sorting is possible, as you can use ORDER clause, but it don't know, how efficient it will be.

It may not be necessary though. You will be able to join the tables on the INDEX column.